# How to get G-Force Sensor in Android?

Tags: android, sensors, calculation

Is there a way to read or calculate the G-Force from my device into a TextView using Android Studio?

Comment: What is the "G-Force Sensor"? Do you mean the accelerometer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the accelerometer? It's built into phones to measure movement on the X-, Y-, and Z-axes. It certainly is possible to display these on a TextView. To do so, you want to first declare a `SensorManager` and a `Sensor` in your `MainActivity` class like so:

```java
private SensorManager SensorManager1;
private Sensor AccelSensor;
```

`SensorManager` basically allows you to access the device's sensors and the `Sensor` itself is there to retrieve data from a sensor of your choice.

In your `OnCreate()`, you can set them up.

```
SensorManager1 = ( SensorManager ) getSystemService( SENSOR_SERVICE );
```

Once assigned to the system's sensors, you can now continue to set up your individual sensor.

```
AccelSensor = SensorManager1.getDefaultSensor( Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER );
```

`AccelSensor` is now set up to receive data from the phone's accelerometer, however, it is not yet connected to the `SensorManager`, which means that it has no access to the readings.

```
SensorManager1.registerListener( this, AccelSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL );
```

To do so, connect it to the `SensorManager` with `registerListener()`.

Now, you will get a red underline on the above code. Don't panic, you just haven't implemented the required methods yet. We are using "this" to refer to the `SensorEventListener`, but Android Studio does not see it. To do so, take your `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity` and add `implements SensorEventListener` to it. It should end up being:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
...
}
```

Now the red line from earlier is gone, but a new one is here! All you have to do now is right-click the `implements SensorEventListener` and Android Studio should give you an option to Implement Methods. Click that and implement `onSensorChanged()` and `onAccuracyChanged()`. You will now see two new functions pop up in your code.

We don't need `onAccuracyChanged`, so just leave it be:

```
@Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged( Sensor sensor, int accuracy ) {
        // unused, but android studio needs this here
    }
```

`onSensorChanged` *is* what we need. This is what is called every time the sensor updates, or changes. Here is where we can update the TextViews from earlier to show the values.

`SensorEvent`'s `event` is an array of 3 values. These three values are the X, Y, and Z readings of the accelerometer and are located at indices 0, 1, and 2 respectively. So, we can take those and simply concatenate that with a letter (to show which reading is which) like so:

This should display each value as "[X/Y/Z] = [value]"

```java
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged( SensorEvent event ) {
        ViewX.setText( "X = " + event.values[ 0 ] );
        ViewY.setText( "Y = " + event.values[ 1 ] );
        ViewZ.setText( "Z = " + event.values[ 2 ] );
    }
```

And that's it! You now have a working sensor to view readings from the accelerometer and they will be displayed on the TextViews.